# Api.ai Multiple Items in Order System

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am creating a sample app in which multiple items as per categories can be chosen. Please see flow as below.

If i want to opt 3 items and all are falling in different categories. The configuration will like this.

A) Item 1
Category 1
Price1
ingrdient1

B) Item 2 
Category 2
Price2
ingrdient3

C) Item 3
Category 3
Price3
ingrdient3

So to achieve this i have to create parameter1, parameter2, parameter3 and so on.

Is there any way in api.ai which supports collection concept like object[0], object[1], object[3] ....

here object[0] holds

A) Item 1
Category 1
Price1
ingrdient1

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

Not currently.

Api.ai are working on List entity, [comment here on their forum](https://discuss.api.ai/t/list-entity/247/3). But currently they don't support objects or arrays being passed as parameters.

You would have set up entities and parameters for price, item, category, ingredient to be passed to your own webservice.

Try asking on their forum though, they're very open to suggestions and improvements for the platform.